# Find the MS Word Table that contain a specific text

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word, vsto

I have a MS Word document look like this
[image]

Now I want to find which table contains the phrase "/CCID_ntRow/". As you can see from the document structure, it's the second table. But every table I loop through,  the return of Find.Execute returns true.
Here is my code:

```
int whichTable = 1; //starting index is 1, not 0

do {
    doc.Tables[whichTable].Range.Find.ClearFormatting();
    doc.Tables[whichTable].Range.Find.Wrap = MSWord.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
    doc.Tables[whichTable].Range.Find.Text = "/CCID_ntRow/";
    doc.Tables[whichTable].Range.Select();
    isFound = doc.Tables[whichTable].Range.Find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    if (isFound == true) {
        //everytime, isFound returns true. The right must be 2
        break;
    }
    whichTable++;
} while (true);
```

Please help me solve this out. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

We can convert all the elements Tables to an IEnumerable of type Table, then we can proceed to use LINQ queries to obtain the required table.

```
var requiredTable = Tables.Cast<Table>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Range.Text.Contains("SOME TEXT"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Range.Find.Execute is wrong in your code. Try the below it works

```
   isFound = doc.Tables[whichTable].Range.Find.Execute("/CCID_ntRow/", ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```